# Delete entire row based on column using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataset (csv) in the form:

```
ship_id,speed,LON,LAT,
00x1,7.4,2.17105,41.31353
00x1,7.4,1.935983,41.04712
00x1,7.4,-5.381285,36.11647
```

and I have a list that contains the lat and lon of several points as below:

```
for i in range(len(array_points2)):
    print array_points2[i].lat, array_points2[i].lon
```

Output:

```
1.935983 41.04712
-0.9617717 37.51845
14.70076 35.76273
```

I want to iterate through the elements of the list and if the lat and lot is the same with any row's LON,LAT then this row to be deleted.

So far my code doesn't work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/repos/master/testdat.csv')
for i in range(len(array_points2)):
    df[df.LAT != array_points2[i].lat]
    df.to_csv('/home/antonis/master/testdat_new.csv', sep='\t')'
```

Also, I have to write the results in another file? The deletion does not aplly in place?

The expected output result is :

```
ship_id,speed,LON,LAT,
00x1,7.4,2.17105,41.31353
00x1,7.4,-5.381285,36.11647
```

Comment: Hint – create DataFrames out of both files and using something like `numpy.where` to compare each `LON` and `LAT` value... Something like `mask = np.where((main_df['LON'] != other_df['LON']) & (main_df['LAT'] != other_df['LON']), 0, 1)`... Assign `mask` to the `main_df` then remove rows where `mask == 1`

Comment: I am new to pandas o this sounds very difficult at this point. can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way, first convert your array of Points into a list of lists:

```
list_lon_lat =[]
for point in array_points2:
    list_lon_lat.append([point.lon, point.lat])
```

Then build a dataframe for the list of dictionaries and rename columns so they match original dataframe:

```
df_lonlat = pd.DataFrame(list_lon_lat, columns=['LON','LAT'])
```

Finally, drop from the orginal dataframe the intersection of the original and the lonlat dataframes.

```
df.drop(df.merge(df_lonlat).index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I don't understand this lon_lat = [[2.171050, 41.31353],[1,0]]. This are the values from csv file?

Comment: those are just dummy values i created to test the list of lists, they are made up

Comment: Yes, it is in the Output above in my answer

Comment: It is a list of dictionaries then?

Comment: The array_points2 output is : [<Point lat:1.935983 lon:41.04712>, <Point lat:-0.9617717 lon:37.51845>, <Point lat:14.70076 lon:35.762730>]. The elemnts inside are Point objects. I can acces the lat and lot of each with array_points2[0].lon and array_points2[0].lat for example

Comment: Oh I see, first we need to convert that into a list of lists or list of dictionaries (format that will be accepted by the DataFrame constructor pd.DataFrame()

Comment: Can you help me with that? I try but I dont find a solution

Comment: For some reason, this does not work to me. I have extra code df.to_csv("/home/antonis/repos/master/testdat_REF.csv", sep='\t') to write the new results but the new .csv contains all the rows. Perhaps I do something wrong

Comment: add inplace=True to the drop

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: Mmm, I don't know maybe you can show at which step the algorithm is not working..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach .

Fist convert the list to a Dataframe.

```
dfy = pd.DataFrame(array_points2, columns=['ship_id','speed','LON','LAT'])
```

Then drop the rows where LON or LAT of your original Dataframe is same as that of your list which is now a Dataframe.

```
df = df.drop(df[((df.LON == dfy.LON) | (df.LAT == dfy.LAT))].index)
```

The output would be--

```
ship_id,speed,LON,LAT,
00x1,7.4,2.17105,41.31353
00x1,7.4,-5.381285,36.11647
```

Then save the Dataframe df as csv file using the following code--

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Hope this answer solves your problem!